# What is the most secured UEFI publicly available?

Tags: monitoring, spyware, bios

It is very scary to know that spywares were installed on some largely commerciallized laptops at the BIOS level. Example: [Lenovo ThinkPad spyware](http://gadgets.ndtv.com/laptops/news/lenovo-in-the-news-again-for-installing-spyware-on-its-machines-743952)

What UEFI would you recommand to have in order to track any possible spyware.

I would need full monitoring of every UEFI activity and if possible make it available at the OS level

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you ask this shows you haven't understood the problem to its fullest extent:

> I would need full monitoring of every EUFI activity and if possible make it available at the OS level

The UEFI potentially runs at privilege levels higher than any software that you can execute on your system. Hence, it's untraceable, unless it wants to be traced.

You might want to watch [this talk introducing the privilege levels that UEFI can enter.](https://media.ccc.de/v/31c3_-_6129_-_en_-_saal_2_-_201412282030_-_attacks_on_uefi_security_inspired_by_darth_venamis_s_misery_and_speed_racer_-_rafal_wojtczuk_-_corey_kallenberg).

And, also, that talk demonstrates how to gain these same privileges to mess with what would normally firmware protected from modification.

In other words: While there is free and open source UEFI firmware for a couple of notebooks (google: coreboot), there's no absolute security.

Comment: warning: Coreboot is Open Source, *but maintained by Google engineers*. It may contain spyware. I wouldn't trust it. There is also Libreboot.